# Setting the forgotten password from email address in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to configure Sitecore to send emails from a specific email address when a CMS user goes through to reset their password.

Currently the email is sent from someone@example.com but it isn't in any of the config files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't find *from* email address in a config file because it is hard-coded.

You can change this manually by going to `[website_root]/sitecore/login/passwordrecovery.aspx` and editing `MailDefinition.From` property on `line 39`.

**Edit:**
Might be a good idea to edit codebehind for that page and pull sender address from a config file.